# update string through part of string in case of appearance special event in string via MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a varchar field that contains a description with variable lenght. I want to update it in the form shown below (delete the part after `20161203_` and before `LC` (`1001_`) in the first case) in case of appearance `LC` in string.

For example if the table contained:

```
|col1 |
+-----+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE |
|20161217_1001_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH  |
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE|
|20170117_2003_LC_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE |
```

I want a query that will return:

```
|result|
+------+
|20161512_NL_Luxus_1_DE|
|20161217_LC_YoBirthdayNo_A_CH|
|20161512_NL_SDT_4_DE|
|20170117_LC_YoBirthdayYes_A_DE |
```

I tried it like:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 LIKE '%LC%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, '_', 1), '_', 2)
```

but that´s not correct...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the `_LC_` always be preceded by a four digit number?

Comment: I was still on the road last night - so now my answer: Yes, at the moment it is - but later it could be longer.. is the result you gave me regardless of the number of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also first attempted to do this using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, but then gave up when it appeared that it only supports single character delimiters.  My fallback solution is just to use a combination of `INSTR` and `SUBSTRING`.  In the query below, I concatenate together the updated `col1`, in the process splicing out the four digit number which you want to remove.

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 8),                  -- keep 8 digit date
                  SUBSTRING(col1, INSTR(col1, '_LC_')))   -- and everything from _LC_
WHERE col1 LIKE '%_LC_%'                                  -- onwards
```

Comment: See my coment up above - is the result you gave me regardless of the number of numbers?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner No, my original answer assumed a four digit number.  I updated making the assumption that you just want to keep the 8 digit date, followed by `_LC_ ...`.  This avoids the issue of having to know how wide that number might be.

Comment: Ok:it will work for the next X month - till my department decides to solve things differently again: I will report again when it is time ... First of all thank you very much!

Comment: Oh - I have misunderstood (or read too late): The new solution fits so much better - thank you (again) for your support!